# Silverlight WCF "slsvcutil.exe" - How to set timeout

Tags: silverlight, sdk, timeout, xamarin.ios, slsvcutil

We use the Silverlight SDK to generate our WCF proxies (slsvcutil.exe)

How do we set the connection/response timeout with the resulting class to a different level?

*Note: We're using MonoTouch.NET on an iPhone so there is no app.config. All settings must be done in code.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you create your own binding and endpoint address then intstaniate the client using those? A simple example (Which includes a timeout option):

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
// more attributes for the binding

EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("https://mywcfserver.com/WCFService.svc");
ClientProxy client = new ClientProxy(binding, endpointAddress);
```

just to note, the bindings you define in the code, should be the same as the binding definited the web service's app.config.